# How do I work with cabal-install when I can't control the path?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-platform, cabal-install, vista64

I am on stuck on a vista machine on which I am not the admin. I installed Haskell Platform to a place that I control. The problem is I am as far as I know on able to control the path. When I try to run cabal.exe, I get an error.

```
H:\Haskell\Platform\lib\extralibs\bin>cabal.exe install cabal-install
cabal.exe: The program ghc version >=6.4 is required but it could not be
found.
```

How do I make it so I can use Haskell Platform as I were a home user. Can a temporarily adjust the path, and if so, to what?

Comment: how about `cabal install --help` ... `cabal install blah --with-ghc=some_path_to_ghc --with-ghc-pkg=...` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here was just that the windows path itself needed to be updated to make sure the ghc executable was there.